# Why would an HTML.Action cause the Home/Index method to be called repeatedly only when user is not authenticated?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

In _Layout.cshtml, I use the following call:

```
@Html.Action("GetCurrentAnnouncement", "Announcement", new { isUserLoggedIn = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated })
```

It calls this method:

```
public async Task<PartialViewResult> GetCurrentAnnouncement(bool isUserLoggedIn)
    {
        var announcement = await _announcementService.GetCurrentAnnouncement(isUserLoggedIn);

        if (announcement == null) return null;

        var model = new AnnouncementDisplayViewModel();
        model.AnnouncementId = announcement.AnnouncementId;
        model.AnnouncementText = announcement.AnnouncementText;
        model.DisplayToAll = announcement.DisplayToAll;
        model.HyperText = announcement.HyperText;
        model.Url = announcement.Url;
        model.StartDate = announcement.StartDate;
        model.EndDate = announcement.EndDate;

        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_Announcement.cshtml", model);
    }
```

This works just fine when a user is already authenticated.  The HomeController's Index method is called just once, I can break into the GetCurrentAnnouncement method and watch it do its' thing perfectly, and the _Announcement.cshtml is displayed just fine.

[image]

_Announcement.cshtml:

```
@model Announcement.AnnouncementDisplayViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 announcement">
        <span class="full-announcement-text">@(Html.DisplayFor(m => m.AnnouncementText))</span>
        @if (Model.HyperText != "" && Model.HyperText != null)
        {
            <br />
            <a href="@Model.Url" target="_blank" class="announcement-link">@Model.HyperText</a>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, if I log out, the Home/Index method gets called repeatedly until Chrome warns me briefly about too many redirects and then I get an HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long. with a ridiculous looking querystring http://localhost:54578/?ReturnUrl=%2F%3FReturnUrl%3D%252F%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252F%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252F%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252F%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252F%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252F%2525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525253D%252525252525252F%252525252525253FReturnUrl%....

In that situation, I never hit the GetCurrentAnnouncement method once.  Just Home/Index over and over until it is borked.  I cannot for the life of me figure out what might be going on.  It doesn't matter if I make the GetCurrentAnnouncement method non-async and return a static viewmodel, with no isUserLoggedIn param passed to it, or anything else I have tried.  Here's HomeController's Index method.  It always gets to the last line where it returns the HomePage view (over and over):

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //Healt check to see if we have connection to the APIs and the DB
        var healtCheck = _heartbeatService.GetHeartBeat();

        if (healtCheck == null || healtCheck.Result == null || (!healtCheck.Result.Success))
        {
            return View("Error");
        }

        var user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;

        bool userAuthenticated = (user != null) && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

        if (userAuthenticated)
        {
            if (user.IsInRole(Roles.WebAdmin) || user.IsInRole(Roles.Maintenance))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Shop");

            }
            if (user.IsInRole(Roles.Shop))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Referral");
            }
        }

        var viewModel = new LoginViewModel();
        return View("HomePage", viewModel);
    }
```

I did find this somewhat interesting line in HomePage view, but the form never gets submitted and everytime I hit it, ViewBag.ReturnUrl is null, so IDK:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
```

Comment: By any chance does the homepage view redirect the user back to Index()?

Comment: It's a good question, but there doesn't seem to be anything that would fit that bill in the HomePage view.  There are a few breakpoints I can hit in that view of Razor markup that let me know it is being loaded.  But you're right, something is causing that redirect.  If I take out that @HTML.Action, everything is as it should be...  except I can't implement that Announcement feature I need.

Comment: How is your authentication implemented then? That would be the next question

Comment: HomePage contains a form (see line added above for the BeginForm) which calls login method of AccountController.  Looks like we have kind of a homespun (vs say oAuth or similar) authentication scheme and user info is stored in claims.  Would it be helpful to add the somewhat lengthy _Layout.cshtml if I take the time to redact it etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!  I should have posted the whole AnnnouncementController; it had an [Authorize] attribute at the top level.  By using an [OverrideAuthorization] attribute on the GetCurrentAnnouncement method (which needs called regardless of whether a user is logged in or not), it solved all of my headaches.  Thanks for all the clues, MVC.  The more I get to know you, the less I like you, and I did not like you to begin with .